# Какие можно создать индексы для оптимизации запроса?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть две простенькие таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
     id INT,
     title VARCHAR2(14),
     details VARCHAR2(13)
) 

CREATE TABLE answers (
     id INT,
     question_text VARCHAR2(10),
     details VARCHAR2(9),
     order INT,
     score INT
)
```

Я написал к ним следующий запрос:

```
SELECT question_text, title 
FROM answers JOIN questions 
                  ON answers .id = questions.id
ORDER BY title, question_text
```

Какие индексы могут быть добавлены для оптимизации данного запроса? По столбцам title и question_text?

Comment: для адекватности тут не индексы надо добавит, а первичные и внешний ключи, в частности во второй таблице, надо полагать нужно добавить id инкрементный, а существующий id перемеиновать в question_id.  Сортировать надо тоже наверное не по question_text а по order

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю индексов вообще нет?
Если так, то начни с кластеризованных, они в 99% случаев нужны.
Если у тебя связь 1 к 1, то других и не надо, но тогда стоит задуматься над объединением этих таблиц в одну. Если, в будущем, у тебя будет несколько ответов на 1 вопрос, то нужно будет добавить в столбец "questions_id" в таблицу "answers" и на нём создать некластеризованный индекс.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ID ON questions(id)
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ID ON answers(id)
--CREATE INDEX IDX_QUESTION_ID ON answers(questions_id)
```

Код лучше оформить в таком порядке(от одного ко многим):

```
SELECT a.question_text, q.title 
FROM questions AS q
JOIN answers AS a ON q.id = a.id
ORDER BY q.title, a.question_text
```